# Hiding your password when typed as an argument into a bash shell / command prompt?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, powershell

[image]I was using weechat when I noticed that if I do a command in the program like `/msg IdentServ identify <my-password>` that it actually blanks out your password as you're typing it...see image below:

However...when I use a program in Linux or Windows that requires that you type your password in the Terminal, Cmd.exe or Powershell, passing it usually as a command line argument, it just leaves it out there for everyone looking over your shoulder to see.

Is there a feature like this in Windows or Linux?  Is it also possible to do this when pressing the up-key prior to a timeout after which it no longer operates in this manner to re-run the same command again?

I'm aware of things like `sudo` and ssh keys for linux, which does kind of solve the problem, but not really aware of anything but Powershell "secure strings" for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get much to know, by the details you provided, however I assume the question title itself makes all of it and will answer that :

> Hiding your password when typed as an argument into a bash shell / command prompt ?

Being a linux user, I would answer it for `bash shell`. You can write a shell script that prompts for password like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n Password:    # Prompt for entering password 
read -s password     # read password by suppressing it using -s option
echo
echo $password       # print password
```

Here `-s` in **[read](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)** command means `suppress` that suppress the output stream to show anything. Thus having your password invisible when you type it.

`NOTE` : It works in a shell script, but to make it work in applications such as weechat, you have to change the underlying code or better write a shell script that does it when you open the app for the first time.

To read more on this topic follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316730/linux-scripting-hiding-user-input-on-terminal/4316747) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing/3980904#3980904)

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: I suppose you can `unset` the variable then to make it go away as a variable?