# "read -s" equavalent for windows?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, cmd.exe

In Linux you can [type and store a value without displaying what you are typing](https://superuser.com/a/1315965/2293) by adding the `-s` argument to the `read` command.

Is there an equivalent command in Windows?

Comment: There just was a similar question on SO that was answered in various ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nurky.rf.gd/dl/conset.zip
Password is:broughtToYouByTheG00D0n3$
( Password is there to stop the provider from scanning the archive, just to point out)

After extracting, type:

```
conset /PH myValue=
```

Input something and hit enter. Now type this to see did it worked:

```
echo %myValue%
```

Good luck :)

Comment: What is the provider?  And why is there a zip file to download?  Sorry I'm not following...

Comment: I understand about the `conset` not echoing the password and setting it inside an environment varialble.

Comment: It's my website. I often use it for backing up my files but also use it for other software instead of just pictures and videos. The hosting provider of that site doesn't allow .exe files, even if you packed them. Setting the password to the archive seems to help.

Comment: Oh I get it...so that tool `conset` doesn't come with Windows anymore?

Comment: As far as I remember it was available in Windows 2000 and XP. Though I could be wrong, but yes it doesn't come with Windows anymore apparently.

Comment: conset.exe is a tool written by Frank P. Westlake and was AFAIK never part of any windows version. The way it treats the environment isn't compatible with win10(64). Frank lost his source code and didn't update his tools.

Comment: Probably reverse engineer the executable would fix that but who's gonna do that? In 99% cases no one.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an equivalent for just `read` without the `-s` flag.
What you input **will** be displayed, as `set` does not support a flag equivalent of `-s`, but it's a starting point security-wise, as at least your secret won't be kept in your terminal history.

```
# set /P PASSWORD="> "
> secret

# echo %PASSWORD%
secret
```